# Angular2 using .filter() to get index and object from array?

Tags: angular, indexing, filter

Is there any way to make the following code simpler?

```
let objectModified = this.objectsModified.filter(objectModified => {
  if(objectModified.index === this.objectCurrent.index) {
    return objectModified;
  }
})[0]; /*[0] because there is no way the could be .length > 1 */

if(objectModified) {
  let index = this.objectsModified.indexOf(objectModified);
  this.objectsModified[index] = "something";
}

else {
  this.objectsModified.push("something");
}
```

It seems to me that there must be a smarter, more readable solution. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: can you describe what your objectsModified list is supposed to represent?  Because it seems to be just a list of "something" strings... not objects

Comment: nope it's an array of objects ... `"something"` was only used to simplify this example.

Comment: I'm asking because you're modifying the currently found object in place and then pushing that same object back on the list.  So, your list will now have two different references to the exact same object. Is that the behaviour you want, or is the objectsModified list supposed to be like a history storing a copy of each version of the object?  I ask because if it's the former behaviour you want, you can greatly simplify your code - but i'm not sure why you'd want that behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) would simplify things:

```ts
let objectModifiedIndex = this.objectsModified.findIndex(
  objectModified => objectModified.index === this.objectCurrent.index
);
if (objectModifiedIndex !== -1) {
  this.objectsModified[objectModifiedIndex] = "something";
} else {
  this.objectsModified.push("something");
}
```